# How to show JavaScript code saved in a php variable on page?

Tags: php

I have a php variable that has JavaScript code

```
<?php
$code = '<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "url": "https://www.example.com/"
}
<script>';
?>
```

Somewhere on my page I want to print this code but it do not show up

```
<pre>
<?php $code; ?>
</pre>
```

I expect output

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "url": "https://www.example.com/"
}
</script>
```

It inserts the code in the page but not showing because of `script` tags.

Keep in mind that I can't change content of variable.

Comment: @arundeepchohan the code is there in the page but not showing

Comment: What did you want displayed? Just the url?

Comment: don't use ``<pre>`` tag, just echo the content using ``<?php echo $code; ?>``

Comment: be careful, according to your code above, your script tag needs to be closed

Comment: @FlorentRoques It was my typo, I have edited the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `htmlspecialchars`, which encodes html special characters.

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($code);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the best answer but this will work for you :

```html
$code = '<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "url": "https://www.example.com/"
}</script>';

$str_to_replace = ["<script type=\"application/ld+json\">", "</script>"];
$str_replaced = [""];

$code = str_replace($str_to_replace, $str_replaced, $code);
$php_variable = json_decode($code);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($php_variable); echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: An alternative using regex is something like: `$inside=preg_replace('/\n?\<\/?script[^\>\n]*\>\n?/','',$code);`.